# Hide plugin list

Tags: plugins

I want to hide my plugin list. Suppose anyone can see which plugin I use from [this site](http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/). How can I hide my plugin list from here? I use WordPress new version, and I want to always update my plugin but don't want anyone can see my plugin name. How can I do that?

```
function cws_hidden_plugin_12345( $r, $url ) {
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check' ) )
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to explain what you need to do and for what reason a little more clearly? Your question is hard to follow.

Comment: please go this site http://whatwpthemeisthat.com and give here this domain name http://projuktichowa.com and click "check site". here you can see which plugin and theme i use this site. i want no one can see which plugin i use for this wordpress site.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress needs themes and plugins to be in web-accessible folder, so that any scripts and styles from them can be downloaded by browsers and work.

From there it's technologically easy to detect such resources in page source and/or proactively scan site for presence of files belonging to popular plugins.

There is nothing to be done about that, short of massive layer of moving and anonymizing any files that need to be loaded. I am not aware of any solutions the purposely do this. Plugins that concatenate scripts and styles can have *partial* side effect like this.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-plugins/?ref=commonninja

The Hide Plugins plugin does it all.

Comment: From a comment on the question it looks like OP wants to hide the plugin from an external plugin scanning tool, whereas your plugin looks like it just hides them from the dashboard plugin list.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is just remove generator...

```
    foreach ( array( 'rss2_head', 'commentsrss2_head', 'rss_head', 'rdf_header', 'atom_head', 'comments_atom_head', 'opml_head', 'app_head' ) as $action ) {
        remove_action( $action, 'the_generator' );
    }
```

after that - whatwpthemeisthat.com  will ignore you.

Comment: where i imput this code? in function.php ?

Comment: `functions.php` perfectly suits for that.

Comment: i already imput this code in function.php but it's not work.